# The OpenAI File encountered an error during file upload （.json: Invalid file format）？

Tags: openai-api

I tried making my json file into the new assistant but it say this error
There was an error uploading the file appointments.json: Invalid file format. Supported formats: [‘c’, ‘cpp’, ‘csv’, ‘docx’, ‘html’, ‘java’, ‘json’, ‘md’, ‘pdf’, ‘php’, ‘pptx’, ‘py’, ‘rb’, ‘tex’, ‘txt’, ‘css’, ‘jpeg’, ‘jpg’, ‘js’, ‘gif’, ‘png’, ‘tar’, ‘ts’, ‘xlsx’, ‘xml’, ‘zip’]

```js
const file = await AssistantHandler.UploadFiles({
         file: [
            {
               "start": "2023-11-14T15:30:00+01:00",
               "summary": "skdkasd",
            },
            {
               "start": "2023-11-14T19:00:00+01:00",
               "summary": "jadslk",
            },
         ],
         user_id: "ouG890XHkqh79nvlHQzftGkjKvEE",
         date: "2021-10-17",
         type: "prescription",
      });
```

```js
static CreateLocalFile = async ({ file, user_id, date, type }) => {
      try {
         const filePath = path.join("/tmp", `${user_id}-${type}-${date}.json`);
         file.forEach((obj) => {
            const jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);
            fs.appendFileSync(filePath, jsonString + "\n");
         });
         return filePath;
      } catch (error) {
         console.error("Error creating local file:", error.message);
         throw error;
      }
   };

   static async UploadFiles(params) {
      try {
         const filePath = await this.CreateLocalFile(params);
         const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, { encoding: "binary" });

         const response = await this.openai.files.create({
            file: fileStream,
            purpose: "assistants",
         });

         fs.unlinkSync(filePath);

         return response;
      } catch (error) {
         console.error("Error uploading file:", error.message);
         throw error;
      }
   }
```